# Define function based on link

Tags: php, jquery

I want to open an function for every existing kind of links on my pages.

example:

when I click on a .pdf link it opens and pdf-function.
if a click on a .mp3 link it opens a player, etc

But I want a way to do it without editing the links.

Comment: This very vague.  It is also unclear whether you undersntad the difference between client-side scripting (i.e. javascript) and server-side scripting (i.e. PHP).

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I have a lot of posts with links and I want to know how I could call a function everytime an user clicks in a link to an specific file extension

Comment: Does this have to be done with PHP? jQuery makes the event handling possible, but if it needs to interact with PHP, you'll need to add an AJAX call, which is somewhat lengthy.

Comment: It havent to be done with PHP, I just found it was easier in PHP. How could I do it in jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQuery you can easily attach a handler to all of the links of the page. Within that handler you can test the `href` and take whatever action is appropriate. If you want to prevent the default link navigation for certain types of link just call `event.preventDefault()` for those types:

```
$(document).on("click","a", function(e) {
   if (/\.pdf$/i.test(this.href)) {
       pdfFunction();
   } else if (/\.mp3$/i.test(this.href)) {
       playMP3(this.href);
       e.preventDefault();
   } // etc.
});
```

The code I've shown uses a delegated event model so that one handler is attached at the document level rather than attaching one handler per link. If you want one handler per link for some reason you can do `$("a").on("click",...)` or `$("a").click(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

So, this really depends on what you're trying to do. But, here's my basic suggestion...

Assuming you're coming from a web page (assuming that's what you mean by links), you have to have a way to trigger on what type of link it is. Very simply, you could add a class to your different types of links to identify what they are. Your HTML would look something like this, perhaps:

```
<a href="http://path/to/file.mp3" class="mp3link">Some Song</a>
<a href="http://path/to/file.pdf" class="pdflink">Some PDF</a>
<a href="http://path/to/file2.pdf" class="pdflink">Some Other PDF</a>
```

Now, you want to trigger on the types of links. How you actually handle what happens depends on whether you can do it all client-side, or if you need to reach back to your server for more work (again, you'll have to decide what you want to do). You can use JavaScript (and, specifically, the jQuery library) to trigger on those classes. Something like...

```
$('.mp3link').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // stop the link from being clicked

  // Define what you want to do here - ajax call back to the server or fire
  // up a client-side media player, or whatever.
});

$('.pdflink').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // stop the link from being clicked

  // Define what you want to do here.
});
```

...and so on for whatever types of interactions and files you have. Now, without a lot more info, I can't get into much more detail, but if you understand the client/server interaction within your application, this should give you a good starting point of how to wire it altogether.

Comment: thanks, but how I can do it without the classes?
I have a lot of links and I don't want to edit link by link